# When should I load and dispose resources

Tags: android, libgdx, resources, assets

I have read a lot about this question, but I would like some advice on how I should approach it in my situation.

I have a user interface with about 8 different Screens, I do not plan on loading/disposing resources when swapping between Screens because that would make for a really poor user experience.

However, I also have 12 Mini-Games that you can start from my UI, which brings me to my question; When should I load and dispose assets?

As I see it I have a Two options:

- Option A: I load every single asset when the game is started, however this seems like a bad solution.
- Option B: I Load only UI assets when the game is started, and then load assets for each individual mini-game when they are started, and dispose of them after they are finished.

If I go with option B, should I then dispose all UI assets before the mini-game is started? That would mean I have to re-load them after the mini-game is finished (each mini-game is 50 seconds long). This does not seem user friendly, but wont it cause memory-leaks if I dont dispose of UI assets when I start a mini-game (user is redirected to UI after mini-game is finished)?

Comment: the best solution is to use the libgdx [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets), load everything and let the assetmanager handle everything for you, you just need to dispose the asset manager when you are not ussing any assets anymore.

Comment: I already use the asset manager, But you still need to load/unload resources

Comment: yes, well, you can load the resources for the first level, while the user is playing you can fire a new thread loading the resources for the next level, when you change the minigame fire a thread that disposes the last level resources and loads the next level assets and so on, sure that you need to check every level change if the assets are loaded, if not make the user wait. for that assetmanager have update(int millis), see the [reference](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html)

Comment: With today devices memory i don't see a reason to do that, unless you have very huge assets, if you load everything on memory would be much more efficient to handle and it will use way less cpu process, just make a benchmarkk of test cases and see what is better.

Comment: @Hllink Thats what I was thinking. But today when I tried on an iPhone 4 the first time, the app crashes after loading 96% of my resources. If I remove about 30% of the resources the app loaded fine. So Im looking for alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real question is how much assets do you have and how big they are (what resolution do they have).

The best idea seems to be to keep everything about graphics in one great [TextureAtlas](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html) - however you have to remember than it is not good idea to create atlas bigger than 2048x2048px - and to load this atlas at the beginning (make some loading screen after splash) then unload at the end of application life.

Of course you should use [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) instance which I suppose you do already.

The same situation in my opinion is when all assets are on two, three atlases. Also music I would treat this way - unfortunately there is no atlas for music :)

---

If amount of assets is really huge and you cannot load them once at the beginning I'm afraid that the best idea is to load them directly before minigame start and dispose directly after end of it - this seems to be the most efficient way to manage your memory. Also user will be prepared to see some loading screens when starting and finishing minigames I guess.

You can also try to implement some [lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) technique of loading assets but it really depends on how many assets you have and what is the characteristic of your application

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I have 1 atlas + 1 background.png for each mini-game I would say, sometimes 2. I use a 1080x1800 resolution so images are quite big.

Comment: 13 so far my friends, asset-folder is 16,9MB so far.

Comment: Then I would load atlas at the beginning and background before and after every minigame (for this game of course:) ). One more option is to resize graphics to 1024x1024 and pack them by fours and scale them up to 1800x1800 again in application but it can cause some quality problems. Last shot - if the minigames are sequential you can load backgrounds for let say 4 of them at the beginning also and then dynamically load before next ones

Comment: I like that, never thot of that approach. Thanks!